# JQPlot - Move the point label to the starting point of the graph

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, graph, jqplot

I have been working on a jqplot horizontal bar graph.

I WANTED TO HAVE THIS OUTPUT (I wanted the Point Labels to be in percentage and should be placed at the starting point of the graph)

[image: Expected Outpt]

**Here is my code.....**

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

voteResults = [[Chinabank,0],['Citibank',100], ['UOB',0]['POSB',0],['OCBC',0]];
// voteResults = [[Chinabank,50],['Citibank',50], ['UOB',0]['POSB',0],['OCBC',0]];

plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [voteResults], {
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            barWidth:15,
            barMargin: 25
        }
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
                showGridline:true,
                markSize:0
            }
        },
        xaxis:{
            ticks:[0,100],
            tickOptions:{formatString:'%d\%'}
        }
    }
});
```

Right now the point labels are displayed after the end of the bar graph and if the point value is somewhere near 100% it won't display anything. And the Points are displayed as a whole number.

Is there a way that I could move the points near the starting point of the bar graph?

The code above displays these sample outputs… I hop you can help me fix my problem :(

[image: Sample Output 1]

[image: Sample Output 2]

Thank you :)

Comment: For starters, `\%` is not a valid escape sequence in JavaScript, so you probably need to use `{formatString:'%d%'}` instead.

Comment: Also, I cannot possibly see how that code generates the sample outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I managed to solve my problem with the help of @Matt and also I add a few lines of code to meet the requirements I wantend. Instead of placing the point labels on the starting point of the bar graph, I placed it at the center to make it more readable and presentable.

Here is my code: (I'm open for suggestions if you feel you have a better solution) thanks

```
var plot = $.jqplot('PollChart', [voteResults], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -50 },
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            barWidth: 15,
            barMargin: 25
        }
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                showGridline: true,
                markSize: 0
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [0, 100],
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%d%',
                showGridline: false
            }
        }
    }
});

// these lines here positions the Point Labels at the center of the graph
var ChartStartingPoint = parseInt($('#PollChart .jqplot-series-canvas').css('left'),10);
var ChartWidth = parseInt($('#PollChart .jqplot-series-canvas').css('width'),10);
var PointLabelLocation = (ChartWidth/2)+ ChartStartingPoint;
$('#PollChart .jqplot-point-label').css('left',PointLabelLocation+'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow the labels to show when the bar is near 100%, use the PointLabels [`edgeTolerance`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#$.jqplot.PointLabels.edgeTolerance) option.

> #### edgeTolerance
>
> Number of pixels that the label must be away from an axis boundary in order to be drawn.  Negative values will allow overlap with the grid boundaries.

---

As I commented on your question, I'm not sure that you actually posted the code you used to generate those charts. [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Aqat3/) is a direct dump of that code (with typos fixed), and [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/G9U9G/) is the closest I could get to your pictures, and that's with a lot of changes to your original code.

Mind posting a jsfiddle that shows how you generated those examples?

Comment: Hi Matt, the code that I posted is actually displaying the first picture of the sample output that I have. I just editted the values of the voteResults and I noticed that the parameters that I passed was all strings that's why the percentage did not take effect. I also revised my code now and I'm currently using your code, thanks to you. I will post the working code.

Comment: Also edgeTolerance doesn't seem to solve my problem so I tried to position the divs at the center by selecting the jqplot-point-label container and position it to the center